# why this code executes properly if and only if I call setTimeOut() function and the code doesn't do its aim exactly without callng it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  var posts = [];
  Post.find({}, function(err, arr) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error");
    } else {
      posts = arr;
    }
  });
  // res.render("home",{par:par,posts:posts})
  setTimeout(function() {
    res.render("home", {
      par: par,
      posts: posts
    })
  }, 300);
});
```

the code only does its aim when using setTimeout function even if the function inside the setTimeout is the same commented function that doesnt work properly

Comment: TL;DR move `res.render()` insider the `Post.find()` callback

Comment: @Phil it has worked, but why didnt it work before?

Comment: The duplicate post linked at the top of your question should explain that